# Python : Extract requests query parameters that any given URL receives

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

**Background:**
Typically, if I want to see what type of requests a website is getting, I would open up chrome developer tools (F12), go to the Network tab and filter the requests I want to see.

Example: 
[image: A sample request URL that the site receives]

Once I have the request URL, I can simply parse the URL for the query string parameters I want.

This is a very manual task and I thought I could write a script that does this for any URL I provide. I thought Python would be great for this.

**Task:**

I have found a library called requests that I use to validate the URL before opening.

```
testPage = "http://www.google.com"
validatedRequest = str(requests.get(testPage, verify=False).url)
page = urlopen(validatedRequest)
```

However, I am unsure of how to get the requests that the URL I enter receives. Is this possible in python? A point in the right direction would be great. Once I know how to access these request headers, I can easily parse through.

Thank you.

Comment: You're possibly after `urllib.parse.urlsplit` and `urlib.parse.parse_qs`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**urlparse**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) method to fetch the query params

**Demo:**

```
import requests
import urllib
from urlparse import urlparse

testPage = "http://www.google.com"
validatedRequest = str(requests.get(testPage, verify=False).url)
page = urllib.urlopen(validatedRequest)
print urlparse(page.url).query
```

**Result:**

```
gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=ISdiWuOLJ86dX8j3vPgI
```

Tested in python2.7

Comment: Hey Rakesh, thank you for the reply. I do not really get your reply though. Could you explain what the result is?